# Error while simulating vhdl code for 4 bit counter in vivado 2015.2

Tags: fpga, vhdl, vivado

Sir,

Whenever i simulate my vhdl code of 4 bit counter in Xilinx vivado 2015.2, i get the error message like following.

> ERROR: [VRFC 10-724] found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"

My vhdl code is

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity my_count is
Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
       clr : in STD_LOGIC;
       y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end my_count;

architecture Behavioral of my_count is
begin
    process(clk,clr)
    variable temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    begin
        if(clr='1') then
            temp := "0000";
        elsif(clk='1' and clk'event) then
            temp := temp + 1;
        end if;
        y <= temp;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

test bench is

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity my_count_tb is
    --  Port ( );
end my_count_tb;

architecture Behavioral of my_count_tb is
component my_count
    port(clk,clr: in std_logic;
         y: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end component;

signal clr,clk: std_logic;
signal y: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    process
    begin
        clk <=not clk after 5ns;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

please help me to solve this error

Comment: temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);

Answer (score 4):

Use the type system instead of fighting it.

Any time you see an uncomfortable double type conversion, especially to another type and immediately back again, like

```
temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);
```

that is fighting the type system, and probably points to a more or less serious mistake in the design.

Instead, think about this:

You want to count - so your data is some form of number, not just a bag of bits.

What range do you want to count? That's not clear from your question, so I'll guess 0 to 15, eliminating negative numbers, covering the 4 bits of output data.

There are 2 obvious choices :

```
variable temp: natural range 0 to 15 := 0; 
variable temp: unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
```

You are already using the correct `numeric_std` library for the latter.

Now there will be a suitable `"+"` operator visible.

What's missing so far is a connection to the output port `y`.

If you are forced by ridiculous coding standards or a huge existing project to keep all ports `std_logic_vector` you'll need a type conversion.

```
y <= std_logic_vector(temp); -- for unsigned temp
y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(temp,y'range)); -- for natural temp
```

If you are allowed to fix a broken design, consider what `y` means in the larger context : if it's an unsigned number such as a memory address, use the right type in the port declaration, then the simplest `y <= temp;` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235819/found-0-definitions-of-operator). @A-Kieffer says

> In VHDL you cannot use arithmetic operators with `std_logic_vector`.

Comment: this error occuring again even i change std_logic_vector to bit_vector.

Comment: please give the correct code with the test bench

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856555).

*"You can't increment std_logic directly, you need to convert it to unsigned and the result back to std_logic_vector using the numeric_std package."*

@apalopohapa also mentioned it in his comment:

*"temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);"*

```
architecture Behavioral of my_count is

begin
    process(clk,clr)
    variable temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000"; 
    begin
        if(clr='1') then
            temp := "0000";
        elsif(clk='1' and clk'event) then
            temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);
        end if;
        y <= temp;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: ERROR: [VRFC 10-91] unsigned is not declared 
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1083] near std_logic_vector ; type conversion expression type cannot be determined uniquely

Comment: errors still present in simulation

Comment: please help me to find the test bench for the following 4 bit counter code.my test bench is not working

Comment: library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity my_count is
    Port ( clr : in STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end my_count;

architecture Behavioral of my_count is

begin
    process(clk,clr)
    variable temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000"; 
    begin
        if(clr='1') then
            temp := "0000";
        elsif(clk='1' and clk'event) then
            temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);
        end if;
        y <= temp;
    end process;
end Behavioral;

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: counting process is not stopping.how to run the pgm to count limited numbers.(for eg. after counting 1 to 15 it will stop automatically)

Comment: @varun It won't stop automatically because you never tell it to stop. All you say is to "temp + 1". If you want it to stop when it reaches "1111" then you need to put in an extra if statement.

Comment: This is my vhdl code and testbench for 4 bit counter. My test bench was not working. i want to stop the counter after some time. Please give the correct test bench.

Comment: vhdl code:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;



entity my_count is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           clr : in STD_LOGIC;
           y : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end my_count;

architecture Behavioral of my_count is
signal temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
begin
process(clk,clr)
begin
if (clr='1') then
temp<="0000";
elsif(clk='1' and clk'event) then
temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);
if(temp="1111") then
temp<="0000";
end if;
end if;
end process;
y<=temp;
end Behavioral;

Comment: --test bench:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity my_count_tb is
--  Port ( );
end my_count_tb;
architecture Behavioral of my_count_tb is
component my_count
  port ( clk: in std_logic;clr: in std_logic; y: inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end component;
signal clk    : std_logic := '0';
signal clr : std_logic:='0';
signal y : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
dut : my_count
port map (clr => clr, clk   => clk, y => y );
P1: process
  begin
   clk  <= not clk after 50ns; clr<='1' after 1000ns; end process P1;exit when clr='1';end Behavioral;

Comment: If you have a new question post it as a new question please. I'm not a resource to personally debug/write your code